# Select in Table ends in Timeout

Tags: c#, mysql

I have programmed a simple C# program which creates random string and calculates the MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, SHA-384 and the SHA-512 Hash. It stores it in my local db. But when i try to do this SQL:

```
SELECT Original FROM md5list WHERE md5 = 'blabla' LIMIT 0, 50
```

But after a while, the mysql Server disconnects and says that the query took too much time. How can i expand the time or make it faster? And is it possible to get the result in one hour?

Comment: did you set indexes on your fields?

Comment: You realize that any properly designed password scheme salts the password, invalidating any efficacy for this technique, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXPLAIN PLAN on the query to see if it's doing a TABLE SCAN.  If you see one, add an index to the `md5` column and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks, worked! But it takes two hours now. I have expanded the max executation time to 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Add indices on `Original` and `md5`. You should get the results much quicker than one hour.

[Create Index Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp)